# React.memo wrapped component fails to re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, memoization, react-flatlist

I'm using React.memo on a message component for a chat app I am making and am having difficulty with it actually updating when needed.

My message component has an element that states its position (whether it's the first, middle, last of a group or on its own) and that changes when a new message is sent for the previous last message. Also, the message component is being used in a flatlist which may be what's complicating this.

Here is the function I am using to compare the messages to their older versions.

```
function messagePropsAreEqual(prevMessage, nextMessage) {
  if (prevMessage?.messageItem?.message?.messageBody == "ABC") {
    console.log(
      "Prev",
      prevMessage?.messageItem?.message?.messageBody,
      prevMessage?.messageItem?.position
    );
    console.log(
      "Next",
      nextMessage?.messageItem?.message?.messageBody,
      nextMessage?.messageItem?.position
    );
  }

  return (
    prevMessage?.messageItem?.message?.id ===
      nextMessage?.messageItem?.message?.id &&
    prevMessage?.messageItem.position === nextMessage?.messageItem.position
  );
}
```

Right now I have it printing the response when I text ABC and what comes up is:

```
Prev ABC groupEnd
Next ABC groupEnd
```

this makes sense to me because when I text it the first time it is assigned groupEnd and there is only one version so I assume prev and next are the same.

Now, when I text another message and the ABC message's position is changed from groupEnd to groupMiddle I expect:

```
Prev ABC groupEnd
Next ABC groupMiddle
```

However, what I'm getting is this

```
Prev ABC groupMiddle
Next ABC groupMiddle
Prev ABC groupMiddle
Next ABC groupMiddle
```

Here is the code for updated the flatlist:

```
  const addMessage = (
    msg:
      | {
          id: string;
          imageUrl: string;
          chatuserID: string;
          imageWidth: number;
          imageHeight: number;
        }
      | MessageModel
  ) => {
    if (msg && chat != undefined && currentChatUser != undefined) {
      const isNotOfGroup =
        messages.length === 0 ||
        currentChatUser?.id != messages[0].message.chatuserID;
      const newMessage = {
        message: msg,
        position: isNotOfGroup ? "notOfGroup" : "groupEnd",
        chat: chat,
        currentChatUser: currentChatUser,
        isLocal: true,
      };
      var existingMessages = [newMessage, ...updateLastMessagePosition()];
      setMessages(existingMessages);
    }
  };

  const updateLastMessagePosition = () => {
    var existingMessages = [...messages];
    const lastMessage = messages[0];

    if (lastMessage != null) {
      if (lastMessage.message.chatuserID == currentChatUser?.id) {
        if (lastMessage.position == "notOfGroup") {
          existingMessages[0].position = "groupStart";
        } else {
          existingMessages[0].position = "groupMiddle";
        }
      }
    }

    return existingMessages;
  };
```

I would be grateful for any help!